# How to set interval time in my case

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to set interval in my app and have something like this

html

```
 <div class="text">
     {{currentItem.name}}
 </div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="pickItem($index)">{{item.type}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.index = 0;
 $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.index];  // set the first item

//The interval start 3 second after the app is loaded
$scope.startInt = $interval(function() {
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.index];
    $scope.index++;

    if(scope.index === $scope.items.length) {
        $scope.index=0;
    }
}, 3000)
```

The above codes will start the interval 'AFTER' the page is loaded for 3 sec. I was hoping to start the interval immediately when the page first loads. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your anonymous function to a named function. Then call the function before using the interval

```
function IntervalFunction() {
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.index];
    $scope.index++;

    if(scope.index === $scope.items.length) {
        $scope.index=0;
    }
}

IntervalFunctin();
$scope.startInt = $interval(IntervalFunction, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

```
var intervalWork = function () {
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.index];
    $scope.index++;

    if(scope.index === $scope.items.length) {
        $scope.index=0;
    }
};

intervalWork();

//The interval start 3 second after the app is loaded
$scope.startInt = $interval(intervalWork, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function notificationsCtrl($scope, $interval) {
    var fun = function(){ 
        $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[$scope.index];
        $scope.index++;

        if(scope.index === $scope.items.length) {
            $scope.index=0;
        };
    fun();
    $interval(fun, 3000);
};
```